# Настройка путей для include qmake

Tags: c++, qmake

когда мы инклюдим какую-то зависимость, то пишем:

```
#include "./../upper_dir/next_dir/TClassName.h"
```

но я точно помню, что как-то настраивал до (код ниже) с помощью qmake, поискал сейчас, не нашёл, подскажите как это сделать пожалуйста

```
#include "TClassName.h"
```

Более того, если в qtCreator создать новый класс и выбрать базовый класс - особый и потом выбрать любой из своих классов, он в новом классе напишет так:

```
#include <TClassName.h>
```

Но при этом подчёркивает как ошибку саму строку с инклюдом
Qt Creator 6.0.2
Основан на Qt 5.15.3 (GCC 11.2.0, 64 бита)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

Comment: @Space Researcher, никогда бы не подумал что скажу такое - советую перейти на cmake )))

Comment: @Ingvar почему?)

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, объяснять долго, и я наверное нормально не смогу. Но если в кратце - система сборки cmake более гибкая (ИМХО), легче настраивается, когда поймешь что и как )))), позволяет пользоваться не только IDE, но и не меняя ничего собирать как из под IDE , так и непосредственно в командной строке. Почитай, попробуй, могу скинуть пример сборки из своего проекта с комментариями. Я не спец, но после 100500 слов матом понял что назад не вернусь. Както-так.

Comment: @Ingvar я в своё время наоборот перешел с смейка на кумейк потому, что он автоматически весь пишется в куткреаторе. В любом случае спасибо за совет , подумаю над этим